# Is there a way to do a multiple param search in Telerik Grid Blazor UI?

Tags: blazor, telerik

I need to perform a multiple search with an external input to the Telerik Grid. As I mentioned, I am using Blazor WASM. Is there any way to do it? I can't find any official documentation suitable for this purpose.

[Grid Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbH66.png)

The expected result would be that if in the input search you put for example id: "4, 5, 7" the grid will update and only show those desired IDs.